# truncating files with windows.h, C

Tags: c, struct, replace, binaryfiles, truncate

I was tasked with creating a random access/ binary list and allowing the program to erase a target record (struct) from it using the windows.h library and it's HANDLE functions.
I'v written the following code in an attempt to truncate files, and while erasing something right at the end of a file seems to work, the section handling files in the middle seems to be making trouble, and im stumped.

```
void erase_record(FILE *file, stct buffer, char *target)
{
HANDLE h;
int jump=0;
int mark;
stct s;
file = fopen("list.txt","rb+");
s.artist = (char*)malloc(20*(sizeof(char)));
s.name = (char*)malloc(20*(sizeof(char)));
while(1)
{
    jump++;
    fread(&buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,file);
    if(!strcmp(target,buffer.name)) // did we find a match? 
    {
        jump--;
        fread(&buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,file); // then check one more time.
        if(feof(file)) // is the match right before the eof?
        {
            fclose(file);
            h=CreateFile(L"list.txt",GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,0,0,OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
            SetFilePointer(h,(jump)*sizeof(buffer),NULL,FILE_BEGIN); // truncate from last
            SetEndOfFile(h);
            CloseHandle(h);
            break;
        }
        else // is it in middle of the file?
        {
            mark = jump; // we mark the struct we wanted to delete
            while(1)
            {
                s.shelf = buffer.shelf;
                s.artist = buffer.artist;
                s.name = buffer.name;
                jump++;
                fread(&buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,file); // find the end of the file first
                if(feof(file))// when we DO find the end..
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            fclose(file);
            h=CreateFile(L"list.txt",GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,0,0,OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
            SetFilePointer(h,(jump)*sizeof(buffer),NULL,FILE_BEGIN); //deleting it!
            SetEndOfFile(h);
            CloseHandle(h);
            file = fopen("list.txt","rb+");
            fseek(file,mark*sizeof(buffer),SEEK_SET); // we erase the marked struct
            fwrite(&s,sizeof(s),1,file);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Can anyone share any insight on what went wrong?

Comment: Very small point which doesn't answer your question, but I noticed your casting the return of `malloc()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc for reasons why one should avoid doing this :)

Comment: Thanks, it's actually very informative

Comment: Again, doesn't answer your question but instead of going through all records to find the last record, could you use `fseek(file, sizeof(buffer), SEEK_END)` and then `ftell()` to save you a while loop? Do all the reads/writes/seek succeed ok... do you detect any errors if you check `ferror()`?

From inspection, it seems good... i can't spot why it's not working. If you could say what errors or symptoms you're seeing that might shed more light on the situ?

Comment: That's actually a great suggestion. I was probably too frustrated with the code that i tried various different things and forgot to simplify it afterwards. It doesn't seem to give off any quirks so i'm really confused

Comment: What are the symptoms of the failure?

Comment: Well, i checked with ferror() but it returned 0. The program just crashes after i try running the section i mentioned and after running through a debug tool i get "Unhandled exception at 0x577514cf (msvcr100d.dll) in Project 5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdcd."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will be related to something below I think. The penny dropped when you said the following:

> Well, i checked with ferror() but it returned 0. The program just
>   crashes after i try running the section i mentioned and after running
>   through a debug tool i get "Unhandled exception at 0x577514cf
>   (msvcr100d.dll) in Project 5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading
>   location 0xcdcdcdcd."

The value `0xcdcdcdcd` is

> "...a debugging value that comes from the bowels of the C runtime
>   library. When you allocate a block of memory in a debug build, it's
>   initialized to this spurious value in the hope of catching bugs.
>   0xCDCDCDCD is non-NULL and is never a valid memory pointer..."
>   (http://www.microsoft.com/msj/1198/c/c1198.aspx).

This implies therefore that something has failed to allocate memory.

First thing I'd do is check the `malloc()` statements do not return `NULL`.

Next, check the return value of `fopen()` is not `NULL`.

Next thing is the following lines...

```
s.artist = buffer.artist;
s.name = buffer.name;
```

They are introducing a **memory leak**. You are *not* copying the string here, you are copying a pointer. Thus the previous memory you `malloc()`'ed for `artist` and `name` is now lost, you'll never be able to `free()` it. I think you probably meant to use `strcpy()` to copy the string from `buffer` into `s.name`, for example?

Also, are you writing the pointers to a file? If you read back `buffer.name` and it is a pointer (I think it must be because you treat it as such) then you're reading back any old address that was valid when you created the file, **but in *this instance* of your program could be completely invalid!** Trying to then dereference that pointer will then cause you headaches!

I would suggest that when you write the structure to the file you do NOT write the pointers `s.name` and `s.artist` but **write the actual strings to the file**. Then read back the strings from the file, then create pointers for them.

```
fwrite(&s,sizeof(s),1,file); // OOPS! You wrote pointer values to a file. 
// These pointers will be invalid addresses in the next program instance!
```

Instead do something like..

```
fwrite(all non pointer members of struct)
fwrite(&s.label, LABEL_LEN, 1, file); // Note, include the string null-terminator
fwrite(&s.name, NAME_LEN, 1, file);   // Note, include the string null-terminator
```

Then when you read, read back the label and name as actual strings...

```
fread(all non pointer members of struct)
fread(&stringBuffer, LABEL_LEN, 1, file);
s.label = strdup(stringBuffer);
fread(&stringBuffer, NAME_LEN, 1, file);
s.name= strdup(stringBuffer);
```

Then later on remember to `free()` `s.name` and `s.label` as `strdup()` has created a copy which you are responsible to dispose of.

Comment: Ill look into this, but so far it appears that by simply fclose()'ing the file worked. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Although `fclose()`ing your file may have helped this one problem, I think you defo have a memory leak, unless you're freeing `s.name/label` before doing `s.name/label = buffer.name/label` and I haven't spotted it? Also storing pointers to a file is a bad idea. You're not guaranteed that these will mean anything in another instance of the program :)

Comment: I thank you for the comments. I'm improving on the code as we speak, though i failed to mention my program initially reopens the file with a "wb" handler (so any old data is erased)

Answer (score 0):

I'v noodled it out. Apparently, i forgot something very important. That was to close (as in `fclose()`) the file. This one is always said to cause problems, and this is an example.